# php preg_match on javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I can use regex on PHP but I want to use it on javascript. My PHP code:

```
<?php
$text = 'http://localhost/music/38ec11aae1.mp3';
preg_match('/music\/(.*?).mp3/mis', $text, $result);
echo $result[1];
?>
```

And it gives me **38ec11aae1**. But I want to do it on javascript. Can anybody help me for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.match` method.

```
var text = 'http://localhost/music/38ec11aae1.mp3';
text.match(/music\/(.*?).mp3/i)
// => ["music/38ec11aae1.mp3", "38ec11aae1"]
text.match(/music\/(.*?).mp3/i)[1]
// => "38ec11aae1"
```